# JQuery Multi Website Preview

Tags: jquery, this, each

i made a php script that handle URL and give back Title, FirstImage and Description of a given url.
In my website, all links i want to replace with previews has "replaced_link" class.
I suppose this function should work, but it does not:

```
var $alinks = $('a.replaced_link');
$alinks.each(function(){
            $this=$(this);
            url = $this.attr('href');
                     $.ajax({
                            type:"GET",
                            url:"data.php?getlink="+url,
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                    $this.append('<img align=center src="images/loader_dark.gif">');
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                    if (data) {
                                            $this.after(data);
                                            $this.remove();
                                    }
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                    $this.find('img').remove();
                            }
                    });
```

});

On a single link, it's working right. If there is more than one "a.replaced_link", all the previous remains with spin loading and only the last take the first link (!!!).
If i remove "$this.remove()", all links will be appended in the last a.replaced_link!
I hope to be clear....
It seems that $this are not splitted as differents objects on ".each"
How to solve?

P.s. I want to remove object because it's possible that i need to trigger this function more than one time... and i don't want to reload each URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in the house! Say

```
var $this = $(this);
```

instead of

```
$this = $(this);
```

Same with url obv.